# Android notification in AlarmReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to be able to create an alarm to ring a notification to the user to start the application every 2 minutes. Everything works fine, but the notification appears when i start my application manually. Here are my code :

*Receiver:*

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = "myactivity";
    CharSequence message = "click to start activity";


    Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, AmslerTestActivity.class);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            scheduledIntent, 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            message, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    nm.notify(1, notif);
    scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);

}
```

*Scheduler:*

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, sender);
```

I want the notification to only ring when the code is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the "scheduler" part of your code in `onPause`, `onStop` or `onDestroy` in order to set the alarm only once your `Activity` stops. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to decide which is best for your purposes. Then, when doing `am.setRepeating`, use `System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 60 * 1000` for the `triggerAtTime` to make the alarm trigger 2 min from the time the `Activity` stops. Then it will repeat every 2 min based on the 3rd parameter, the `interval`, which you currently have set correctly to 2 min.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. but it didn't worked. i placed the "scheduler" in onDestroy and the notification came up the min i click back. the 2 mins is a "testing" thing. the actual one is supposed to be INTERVAL_DAY. i want to run  the notification at 12:01 everyday. it's like the broadcastreceiver is received immediately. is there any thing that i have done wrongly?

Comment: So you're setting the alarm like this now, right?: `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2*60*1000), 2*60*1000, sender);` Because any alarm you set with the trigger time in the past will set off the alarm immediately. Also, maybe you have a previous alarm you set that is still going off. You can cancel it, or more simply power down the device/emulator and power it back on to clear the alarms

Comment: Also, what do you mean "the minute I click back"? If you set the alarm in `onDestroy` then it will only call that code when you call `finish()` on the `Activity` or when the system destroys the activity to save space. So it seems unlikely that as soon as you hit the back button it is setting off the alarm. Something else must be going on here.

Comment: yup. i have a finish() method when i click back. and i think you solved my problem:D my problem is with the time set in cal. thanks! i don't know how to up the points for the answer but thanks a lot!